# Python OS library getProperty

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I am trying to get line.seperator and file.seperator for python using the OS library for file input for my program.

I am trying to set a string to assign that property such as in Java you can do

```
  public static final String      linefeed = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

and

```
  public static final String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

I have trouble finding documentation to do this in Python. Is there a proper way to do this using the OS library.

Can I do `linefeed = os.sep`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jython, then you can use

```html
from java.lang import System
print(System.getProperty('os.name'))
```

Comment: I am not using Jython and want to avoid using it if possible.